# Migrating databases on Heroku fails

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my application one of my models uses a HStore but when I create the extension HStore it fails with the following error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXTENSION"
LINE 1: CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
               ^
: CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

I'm using heroku's free database, as this is just a development deployment so I get the hang of how things work with deploying on heroku. This doesn't fail in my development environment. So whats causing it to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the shared database or the `dev` database? The shared databases do not have hstore. You can upgrade by following these steps:

https://postgres.heroku.com/migration/

All databases will be migrated automatically eventually.